# displaying names in an array

Tags: php, html

using array_chunk I have split an array of names to groups of 4 names, I want to take one of these groups and display it in 4 divs, divs are named after one of the member group names, example group->jhon, mark, giovanni, clara  then  divs are `<div id="jhon></div>`
`<div id="mark"></div>` and so on..
I want to display only the other names in the div that is not equal to the divs name

Comment: could you clearify what you mean by "I want to display only the other names in the div that is not equal to the divs name". Also, can the groups contain the same name twice?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the DIVs at the same point you're outputting the names?  Maybe something like this would help:

```
$garray = array("Jhon","Mark","Josh","Buckwheat");
doGroupDiv("Jhon",$garray);

function doGroupDiv($group, $grouparray) {

  echo '<div id="' . $group . '">';
  foreach ($grouparray as $name) {
     if ($name != $group) echo $name . "<BR>";
  }
  echo '</div>';

}
```

Should yield:  `<div id="Jhon">Mark<BR>Josh<BR>Buckwheat<BR></div>`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
<?php

$namesList = array(
    "Mark",
    "John",
    "Giovanni",
    "Clara"
);

foreach ($namesList as $name) {
    echo "<div id='" . strtolower($name) . "'>\n";
    echo "\t<ul>\n";
    foreach ($namesList as $innerName) {
        if ($innerName != $name) {
            echo "\t\t<li>" . $innerName . "</li>\n";
        }

    }
    echo "\t</ul>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}

?>
```

Which would yield this:

```
<div id='mark'>
    <ul>
        <li>John</li>
        <li>Giovanni</li>
        <li>Clara</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='john'>
    <ul>

        <li>Mark</li>
        <li>Giovanni</li>
        <li>Clara</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='giovanni'>
    <ul>
        <li>Mark</li>
        <li>John</li>
        <li>Clara</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='clara'>
    <ul>
        <li>Mark</li>
        <li>John</li>
        <li>Giovanni</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you exactly what the code is because I have never used array chunks, but it would be something like the following:

```
foreach($array as $name) {
    echo "<div id='$name'><ul>";
    foreach($array as $name2) {
        if($name2 != $name) {
            echo "<li>".$name2."</li>;
        }
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.